# How to remove meaningless codes (HHH000...) from hibernate logs

Tags: hibernate, logging, jboss-logging

I am trying new version of Hibernate (I have used 3.x so far) and Hibernate switched to jboss-logging for whatever reason. This is something I could easily live with, but I like to keep my logs clean and readable and it inserts codes into log messages:

```
16 Feb 2013 19:25:08,352 INFO  [Version:37] - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
16 Feb 2013 19:25:08,357 INFO  [Version:41] - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.9.Final}
16 Feb 2013 19:25:08,358 INFO  [Environment:239] - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
16 Feb 2013 19:25:08,359 INFO  [Environment:342] - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
```

I am using log4j as logging library and my pattern is

```
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c{1}:%L] - %m%n
```

and this suggests that the code is already part of the message that goes to log4j.

So is there any way to remove the codes from the log messages to have

```
16 Feb 2013 19:25:08,357 INFO  [Version:41] - Hibernate Core {4.1.9.Final}
```

I dont want to turn off hibernate logging completely, I just don't want the codes like HHH000412 in it.

Comment: have you solved the problem? if yes please can you share it the solution with us

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging) to see the name of the log4j loggers used by the hibernate internally.

By configuring the log levels of  these log4j loggers to different values , you can configure what the messages are being logged.

For instance , `log4j.logger.org.hibernate=OFF` to disable all the logging from hibernate . `log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ERROR` only will log the messages which log level is at least `ERROR` (i.e the `INFO` level log message will not be outputted)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question probably wasn't clear. I have added an example of what I want to achieve.